# Why this script emits different results when sourcing it or execute it directly?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I have a wrapper script called `my_mv.sh` like below(I am using bash):

```
#/bin/bash
function my_mv(){   
FILE="${@: -1}" # bash or ksh,zsh 
echo $FILE
if [ -f $FILE ];   
then   
    mv -i $@                                                                                                                                                                     
else   
    mv $@   
fi   
}
```

When I use it as a script and run it directly like `./my_mv.sh file1 file2`, the result is as expected. However when I put **function my_mv** into `~/.bashrc` and *source* it, there would be a infinite loop.
So what's the difference between the two methods? How can I change the script so it can be sourced right?

BTW, when using zsh, there is a similar result for the two approaches.

Comment: Works for me.  Is the `#!` line without the `!` as the original, or a transposition error?  How does it appear in `~/.bashrc`, maybe you missed a `}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually name it `my_mv` in your .bashrc, or did you in fact name it `mv`, to override the default?

If so, use `command mv` instead of just `mv` in your function to invoke the system version instead of recursing.

If you just run this as `./my_mv.sh file1 file2`, it will not do anything, because the function is defined but not called.

Comment: In fact, I tested this script by adding an additional line `my_mv file1 file2`(file1 and file2 are in the same directory as `my_mv.sh`). In the `.bashrc` I used `alias mv=my_mv`, and I find this is the problem!Thanks very much.